# Calculos matematicos en tiempo real por medio del evento onchange en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo configurado en un formulario un elemento select con cierto numero de opciones, dependiendo de la opción seleccionada se traen unos valores via ajax de la base de datos y con la siguiente función el hace la comparación de los valores de esos datos.

```
var probar = function(event){

        //event.preventdefault();

        var a_cilindro = parseFloat($('#a_cilindro').val());
        var a_bobina = parseFloat($('#a_bobina').val());

        if(a_cilindro<a_bobina){
            alert('Error: El valor del cilindro en menor al de la bobina');
            $('#a_cilindro ').addClass("uk-form-danger");
            $('#a_cilindro ').removeClass("uk-form-success");
        } else {
            $('#a_cilindro ').removeClass("uk-form-danger");
            $('#a_cilindro ').addClass("uk-form-success");
};

    var select = document.getElementById('my_select');
    select.addEventListener('change', probar);
```

El problema es que esa comparación de los datos no me la hace en tiempo real sino después de que yo selecciono otra opción del select, es decir, si el resultado cumple la condición `(a_cilindro<a_bobina)` me marca el input con la clase `uk-form-success` cuando debería mostrarme el alert de error inmediatamente y marcarla con la clase `uk-form-danger`, pero si yo selecciono una opción que no cumple la condición ahí si me muestra el alert de error basado en el dato de la selección previa y me marca el dato correcto con la clase `uk-form-danger` cuando no deberia mostrarme error y marcar ese campo con la clase `uk-form-success`.

Es algo confuso pero espero puedan entender, en estos casos, ¿como se podría manejar ese tipo de eventos?.

Comment: puedes pasar el html para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola Darwin. La verdad es que no acabo de entender el problema. Según el código que pones (aunque falta el corchete de cierre del `else`), la comparación debería realizarse cuando cambia el valor del elemento `my_select`. ¿No sucede así? ¿Querrías que se produjera en otro momento?
Quizás con un ejemplo más completo....

Comment: @Darwin, el problema es que la comprobación no se ejecuta al cargar la página sino que se hace al cambiar el `select`? Si eso, entonces solo deberías llamar a `probar()`, por ejemplo, justo debajo de `select.addEventListener('change', probar);`

Comment: No entendí nada :(

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entendí:

para que se ejecute la comparación apenas cargue la pagina puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
//apenas cargue la pagina llama a la funcion;
$(document).ready(probar);

//O tambien puedes

//llamar a la funcion cuando cargue la ventana
$(window).load(probar);
```

Ahora para que llames cuando cambie el `value` del `select` puedes poner lo siguiente:

```
 $('#my_select').change(probar);
```